# Как установить Zend Framework на Ubuntu?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, mvc, zend-framework

Подскажите, как правильно установить Zend Framework на Ubuntu. В Ubuntu я новичок.
Пробовал делать, как тут: http://zend-framework.ru/getting-started/, но, честно говоря, как-то сложно.
Нельзя ли просто создать хост, закинуть файлы и кодить что надо?   Расскажите кратко и понятно, кто шарит, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Фреймворк теперь называется по-другому. Laminas. Устанавливать его проще всего через composer

Answer (score -1):

https://launchpad.net/~zend-framework/+archive/ppa

тут адрес репозиторий и деб пакеты. Там же подробная инструкция по установке

вот еще нашел руководство

http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/deb_installation.htm